# String Concatenation - iOS

Tags: ios

As you see in the below image, I am asking user to choose which activities they do in their daily routines.

I would like to get this information in a way as a string and send it to my database.

I have come up a scenario to identify :

Walking :1, 
Biking :2, 
Hiking :3, 
Soccer :4, 
Others: 5, 
None :0

Each Image as shown on the left side of description is a button(IBAction) with iBOutlet.

For example if user chooses, walking, Hiking and Soccer only, my string will be "134"

How could I able to achieve?

```
- (IBAction)walkingBtnAction:(id)sender {
    counter1++;
    if(counter1%2==0)
    {
        [walkingBtnOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if(counter1%2==1)
    {
        [walkingBtnOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    //[self.view addSubview:myButton];
}

- (IBAction)bikingBtnAction:(id)sender {
    counter2++;
    if(counter2%2==0)
    {
        [bikingBtnOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if(counter2%2==1)
    {

        [bikingBtnOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}

- (IBAction)hikingBtnAction:(id)sender {
    counter3++;

    if(counter3%2==0)
    {
        [hikingBtnOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if(counter3%2==1)
    {
        [hikingBtnOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

- (IBAction)soccerBtnAction:(id)sender {
    counter4++;

    if(counter4%2==0)
    {
        [soccerBtnOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if(counter4%2==1)
    {
        [soccerBtnOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

- (IBAction)othersBtnAction:(id)sender {
    counter5++;
    if(counter5%2==0)
    {
        [othersBtnOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if(counter5%2==1)
    {
        [othersBtnOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}

- (IBAction)noneBtnActions:(id)sender {
    counter6++;
    if(counter6%2==0)
    {
        [noneBtnOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if(counter6%2==1)
    {
        [noneBtnOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You'd accomplish this by reading the documentation.  Start with the documentation for NSString.  (And note that there are many diverse things you can do with `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// maybe declare this as a class variable in the .h file
NSString finalString = @"";

- (IBAction)walkingBtnAction:(id)sender {
    if(walkingClicked)
        finalString = [finalString stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
    else
        finalString = [finalString stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"1" withString:@""];
}
```

and now you have to do this for all of your actions

PS: Code was not tested

Comment: brilliant minds think alike!

Comment: Should be an *instance* variable.

Comment: @logixologist what would be your solution?

Comment: for example user clicks on Soccer, then Hiking and then, Walking , and then user decided to unclick on soccer ?

Comment: @casillas I updated it for the unclicking case(else part of the coding). I would suggest to replace the 1 in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create an iVar on that page called choices (for example) then do this

```
[choices stringByAppendingString:@"numberyouwant"];
```

Comment: What if user clicks and string added and then user unclick it?

Comment: I mean for example user clicks on Soccer, then Hiking and then, Walking , and then user decided to unclick on soccer ?

Comment: I would use the tag property of the button and set it to the corresponding number: Example bHiking.tag = 1;

Comment: Recalculate the string each time a click is made

Comment: example: user clicks Hiking.... set choices = @""; then re-evaluate the choices by re-adding up all the clicks. (ignore my last note about the tags, that wont be necessary)